# JQuery Ajax fails on IPhone UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, ajax, uiwebview

I have a web site and I have developed an iPhone app. The iPhone app opens my web site in a `UIWebView`.

The problem is:

In the web site there is a button that makes a JQuery AJAX post which works on mobile Safari but fails in `UIWebView`.

Did anyone encounter the same problem? How could I fix this?